# How to solve Firefox's "samesite" attribute error?

Tags: firefox

I am using Firefox 98. I opened hotmail.com but it gives below error in console(I opened developer tool view by pressing F12):

I have faces with Same site error.

Comment: Try clearing your cache and cookies

Comment: So, are you experiencing any malfunctions? Because most of these are warnings, not errors.

Comment: Open in Firefox the page `about:config` and enter `sameSite` in the search field. Take a screenshot of all the values and include it in your post. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Maybe [create a new Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles). Yours might be misconfigured and/or corrupted.

Comment: Try to set `noneRequiresSecure` to false and restart Firefox. If this is not enough, try also setting  `laxByDefault` to false.

Comment: It would be interesting to compare the `about:config` settings of the two profiles. These settings are found in the profile folder in a file named `prefs.js`. Just compare the two files with a text-compare utility (example [WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/?lang=en)).